# Error when calling AddLabel inside C# Excel Addin: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC)

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, ole, excel-addins

I have an Addin, and when I try to add a Label to addin follow this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442817.aspx

I got this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Cannot insert object.
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Object ClassType, Object Filename, Object Link, Object DisplayAsIcon, Object IconFileName, Object IconIndex, Object IconLabel, Object Left, Object Top, Object Width, Object Height)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl.CreateWrapperAndGetCookie(String name, Double left, Double top, Double width, Double height, Boolean anchor, _OLEObject& outObject)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl.InternalAddOtherControl(Control control, Double left, Double top, Double width, Double height, String name, Boolean anchor)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl.AddControl(Control control, Double left, Double top, Double width, Double height, String name)
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlExtensions.AddLabel(
```

My code to add label:

```
excelLabel = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlExtensions.AddLabel(
        vstoDocument.Controls,
        left,
        top,
        height,
        width,
        myLabelName);
```

I found some same error code but different message answer on Stack Overflow. I tried that but it's still not working.

This error only happens on production mode (installed). It work correctly on development mode. (I used office 365 and windows 8)

Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EPPlus framework, which allows you to send the data to an Excel file in a pure way without Interop.

For example:

```
private void ExportToExcelFile(DataTable table, string filename)
{
    string fileNameOut = filename; // Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Exportation.xlsx";

    if (File.Exists(@fileNameOut)) File.Delete(@fileNameOut);       // If the file exist, then detele the file
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@fileNameOut);

    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
    var wsDt = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(string.Format("Data Exported"));
    // Load the datatable and set the number formats...
    wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true, TableStyles.Light9);


    var headerCells = wsDt.Cells[1, 1, 1, wsDt.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
    var headerFont = headerCells.Style.Font;
    headerFont.Bold = true;  //headerFont.Italic = true;
    //headerFont.SetFromFont(new Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Bold));   //headerFont.Color.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);

    // Disable Autofilter
    wsDt.Tables[0].ShowFilter = false;

    // Formating numeric type or date type
    // wsDt.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";     // Column: TimeStamp "yyyy-mm-dd"

    // AutoFitColumns ALL columns
    for (int i = 1; i <= wsDt.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        wsDt.Column(i).AutoFit();
    /*
    wsDt.Column(1).AutoFit();   // TimeStamp
    wsDt.Column(2).AutoFit();   // FIRSTNAME
    wsDt.Column(3).AutoFit();   // LASTNAME
    wsDt.Column(4).AutoFit();   // TRANSPORT
    wsDt.Column(5).AutoFit();   // MODE
    wsDt.Column(6).AutoFit();   // MODECODE
    wsDt.Column(7).AutoFit();   // OBSERVATIONS
    */

    // set some document properties
    package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Data Export";
    package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "My Company LLC";
    package.Workbook.Properties.Comments = "Data Exported to Excel (OpenXML Format)";

    // set some extended property values
    package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "My Company LLC";

    // save the file
    package.Save();
    //Console.WriteLine("Exported data {0}...");
    //log.Info(string.Format("Exported data: {0}", airlinename));
}



private void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool bandExport_ddMMyyyy = false;
    //show a file save dialog and ensure the user selects
    //correct file to allow the export
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Export to Excel file";

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Microsoft Excel Book 2010-2013(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("¿You wish export in format 'dd/MM/yyyy'? (By default, the TimeStamp values will not be format).", Toolbox.AssemblyTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            bandExport_ddMMyyyy = true;

        if (!saveFileDialog1.FileName.Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (file.Extension.Equals(".xlsx"))
            {
                // Determine the columns to be exported.
                DataTable dataResultsToExport = new DataTable();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    dataResultsToExport.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);

                // Copy the data.
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow dRow = dataResultsToExport.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        // If the column is TimeStamp, we can format it as we want, dd/MM/yyyy.
                        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0 && bandExport_ddMMyyyy)
                            dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", cell.Value);
                        else
                            dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                    }
                    dataResultsToExport.Rows.Add(dRow);
                }

                this.ExportToExcelFile(dataResultsToExport, saveFileDialog1.FileName);

                MessageBox.Show("The exportation works fine!", Toolbox.AssemblyTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid type file, please select the correct type file.", Toolbox.AssemblyTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Spicify the file directory!", Toolbox.AssemblyTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm developing an Excel Addin (not send data to excel).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get answer here. but you can find it yourself. In your case I would do these things:

1. Create a minimum working example, reproducing the problem
2. Check which Excel version have this problem.
3. Check if it depends on build mode (debug/release)
4. Check if it depends on debugger attached (try to start it from Visual Studio without debugging)
5. Check if it because of installation (but start Excel from command line)
6. Check if there are no zombie Excel processes when you start your test session
7. Check if only one version of the addin is enabled in Excel.

If nothing of this helps, come back here with new fact discovered. Excel interop is an area, where are sometimes no ready answer, because you possible the first one who encountered this problem and tried to solve it. Fortunately, it is almost always possible to find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Activex Addins` are disabled in *Settings*.
For Excel 2016, Go to: `File->Trust Centre->Trust Centre Settings`

If there user has selected,

> Disable all Controls without notification.

Then when we add control to worksheet excel will give this error,

> Cannot insert object.