# Excel VSTO refuses to load on particular machine

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

We have VSTO addin for Excel, and it is working on all system except one, I got following error from problem machine.

It seems that there is problem of loading this Excel extension, and there is no clue why this will happen on particular system. Error from problem machine is as follows,

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Cannot insert object.
at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32\[\] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Object ClassType, Object Filename, Object Link, Object DisplayAsIcon, Object IconFileName, Object IconIndex, Object IconLabel, Object Left, Object Top, Object Width, Object Height)
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl.CreateWrapperAndGetCookie(String name, Double left, Double top, Double width, Double height, Boolean anchor, \_OLEObject& outObject)
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl.InternalAddOtherControl(Control control, Double left, Double top, Double width, Double height, String name, Boolean anchor)
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl.AddControl(Control control, Range range, String name)
at TechnicalCalculation.Sheet1.LoadSchedulerUserControl()
at TechnicalCalculation.ThisWorkbook.InitializeService()
at TechnicalCalculation.ThisWorkbook.ThisWorkbook_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.OnStartup()
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.WorkbookExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.OnStartup()
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookBase.OnStartup()
at TechnicalCalculation.ThisWorkbook.FinishInitialization()
at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookBase.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.FinishInitialization()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()
```

We have tried following,

1. Try and fulfill any dependencies, which are fulfilled.
2. VSTO is packaged in a setup file, we have uninstalled and reinstalled it.
3. VSTO, it can emit logs, but logs are not emitted while loading VSTO is getting loaded. It seems that before any code execution from VSTO it is restricted to load with Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real problem was in settings, where there was an issue related to ActiveX Settings, it can be accessed in Excel from **File > Options > Trust center > Trust center settings button > ActiveX setting**.

In my case user selected **"Disabled all the controls without notification."** This was causing me issue while loading my controls using VSTO. This got solved when user selected **"Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions"**

This unblocked controls on ribbon and on side panel, thus solved my problem.

You can find same suggestion on the link
[Stack overflow: Deselect radio button-Disabled all the controls without notification.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66890895/9250682,)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event viewer in Windows to see exception messages that are captured by the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime when you install or uninstall Office solutions. You can use these messages from the event logger to resolve installation and deployment problems. Read more about that in the [Event logging for Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/event-logging-for-office-solutions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2022) article.

The `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` windows environment variable can be set for enabling detailed Outlook and VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) error messages when loading VSTO add-ins. See [How do I enable VSTO error / display alerts?](https://answers.chime.aws/questions/867/how-do-i-enable-vsto-error-display-alerts.html).

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for information, let us try it problem system.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem, it is given in following link
 [Solution is given at last step, for my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182515/error-when-calling-addlabel-inside-c-sharp-excel-addin-system-runtime-interopse)

Comment: There is no accepted answer on the link. Could you describe the solution to the problem?

Comment: Problem was that in excel settings, if disable activex control from loading, VSTO files will throw error as told in that link. The solution is properly given in the last step.

Comment: Again. You are describing the problem which is fine. But you also need to describe the solution. If add to the accepted answer both a describtion of the problem and the solution - then that would greatly help others who come across the same problem as you had.

Comment: Hi, solution is to enable ActiveX control loading enable in excel settings, there is help for the same in the link I mentioned.
I wish to add a snap, but yet now having level, so could not help futher than few text.